# Failure htaccess regax

Tags: .htaccess, regex

I'm trying to get all request to the server to go to the index.php file with the request information.

Also, I want to prevent accessing the index.php file directly.

The second part works fine but I can't do the first part for some reason

```
  #If the request is for index - prevent from accessing the file directly
    RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php(.*)$ - [F,L]

#If the request if not for the receiver - redirect to the api server
#RewriteCond !^(*.)campaigns/(\d+)/pictures(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule  index.php?request=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing stood out to me at quick glance, but if you were fine with solving this in PHP, you could do something at the top of index.php like the following (this is assuming index.php is in the root of the site).

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/index.php' || $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/') {
    header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
    exit;
}
```